# How to send objects through bundle

Tags: android, serialization, android-activity, bundle, parcelable

I need to pass a reference to the class that does the majority of my processing through a bundle.

The problem is it has nothing to do with intents or contexts and has a large amount of non-primitive objects. How do I package the class into a parcelable/serializable and pass it to a `startActivityForResult`?

Comment: "I need to pass a reference to the class that does the majority of my processing through a bundle" -- why?

Comment: I have an object (DataManager), it handles a server and runs a few backends for some GUI's. When ever a new connection is established I want the user to be able to start a new activity that lists in ListView all the active connections and have the user pick one. The resulting data will then tie to a new GUI. This really is just a skin choser for the back end.

Comment: If you're dealing with the same instance of an object over multiple activities, you may want to consider the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). There's a good tutorial [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html).

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Figuring out what path to take requires answering not only CommonsWare's key question of "why" but also the question of "to what?" are you passing it.

The reality is that the only thing that can go through bundles is plain data - everything else is based on interpretations of what that data means or points to.  You can't literally pass an object, but what you can do is one of three things:

1) You can break the object down to its constitute data, and if what's on the other end has knowledge of the same sort of object, it can assemble a clone from the serialized data.  That's how most of the common types pass through bundles.

2) You can pass an opaque handle.  If you are passing it within the same context (though one might ask why bother) that will be a handle you can invoke or dereference.  But if you pass it through Binder to a different context it's literal value will be an arbitrary number (in fact, these arbitrary numbers count sequentially from startup).  You can't do anything but keep track of it, until you pass it back to the original context which will cause Binder to transform it back into the original handle, making it useful again.

3) You can pass a magic handle, such as a file descriptor or reference to certain os/platform objects, and if you set the right flags Binder will create a clone pointing to the same resource for the recipient, which can actually be used on the other end.  But this only works for a very few types of objects.

Most likely, you are either passing your class just so the other end can keep track of it and give it back to you later, or you are passing it to a context where a clone can be created from serialized constituent data... or else you are trying to do something that just isn't going to work and you need to rethink the whole approach.

Comment: Thanks for tour reply. Your right, all I need to do is just pass a reference of a list of objects to my new activity. The new activity will take some data from the list and display a selectable ListView. onSelect,the activity will return a result (some data pertaining to the click object) to the host activity. If I understand correctly, I believe your option 2 handles this most appropriately; how do I get this opaque handle?

Comment: Your other activity can't extract any data from an opaque object to display.  What you probably want to do is create and pass across some surrogate objects of a supported type which contain copies of the information that would be displayed.

Answer (score 160):

You can also use Gson to convert an object to a JSONObject and pass it on bundle. For me was the most elegant way I found to do this. I haven't tested how it affects performance.

In Initial Activity

```
Intent activity = new Intent(MyActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
activity.putExtra("myObject", new Gson().toJson(myobject));
startActivity(activity);
```

In Next Activity

```
String jsonMyObject;
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
   jsonMyObject = extras.getString("myObject");
}
MyObject myObject = new Gson().fromJson(jsonMyObject, MyObject.class);
```

Comment: Since it's a matter of passing stuff between activities it doesn't happen often enough to have great impact on the overall performance of the app. That being said I doubt it would work to serialize the DataManager of the original post since it sounds like it has socket connections and other similar classes.

Comment: Also Google suggests this solution instead of Serialize: check out the last section "Recommended Alternatives" of [this doc page](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html)

Comment: just as a word of warning, I followed this technique for a while but there is a memory limit to what you can pass as a String so be sure your data isn't too big.

Comment: See http://blog.madadipouya.com/2015/09/21/how-to-add-gson-library-to-android-studio-project/ to learn how to add Gson support to your project.

Comment: Smart solution, hats off to you!

Comment: MyObject myObject ... is not always functional, i tried for an object and it show me parsing error message.

Comment: This is not a good idea, since it uses Reflaction, bad for performance =(

Use Parceleable instead.

Answer (score 22):

The **Parcelable** interface is a good way to pass an object with an Intent.

[How can I make my custom objects Parcelable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181526/example-of-implementing-parcelable) is a pretty good answer on how to use **Parcelable**

The official [google docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) also include an example

Comment: or they can also be serializable as well.

Comment: But considerably reduces performance 10x!! Check out this benchmark: http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/

Comment: +1 @Mati's comment, however to put it into context 10x when applied to a single object is the equivalent of 1 ms. So perhaps not as bad as it sounds.

Comment: Agree. The problem is when you deal with collections, which is a very common use case if you are getting resources from a Rest API. But for a single object, shouldn't be something notorious. Anyway, if all the boilerplate code is something getting in your way, you can try this lib that generates that all for you: https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler. A really nice approach!

Comment: Broken link: 404 (not found)

Answer (score 13):

You could use the global [application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) state.

Update:

Customize and then add this to your AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true" android:name=".CustomApplication"
```

And then have a class in your project like this :

```
package com.example;

import android.app.Application;

public class CustomApplication extends Application {
    public int someVariable = -1;
}
```

And because "[It can be accessed via getApplication() from any Activity or Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/framework.html)", you use it like this:

```
CustomApplication application = (CustomApplication)getApplication();
application.someVariable = 123;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I believe you just subclass Application and can then store anything you like.  The xml changes you need are mentioned in the above link.

Comment: As a general design principal, it's a good idea to avoid globals unless you really need them. In this case there are good alternatives.

Comment: Ok, I think I get what you are saying. Just extend Application and throw in a variable holding the object that needs to be passed; I reviewed the reference page and didn't see the necessary xml changes.

Comment: I wanted to write this as an answer too. This is definitely one of the ways to do it. But keep in mind that these objects stay in the memory unless you de-refrence them (or App context is destroyed) and can be occupying space when you don't need them.

Answer (score 13):

You can also make your objects [Serializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html) and use the Bundle's [getSerializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getSerializable%28java.lang.String%29) and [putSerializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putSerializable%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.Serializable%29) methods.

Comment: I tried that and quickly realized it would be impractical. I don't think most of the objects stored in passed class (threads) are serializable. :) thanks though.

Answer (score 11):

Possible solution:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("key", new CustomObject());
```

Class CustomObject:

```
class CustomObject implements Serializable{
 private SubCustomObject1 sc1;
 private SubCustomObject2 sc2;
}
```

Subcustom objects:

```
class SubCustomObject1 implements Serializable{ }

class SubCustomObject2  implements Serializable{ }
```

Answer (score 7):

One More way to send objects through bundle is by using `bundle.putByteArray`

*Sample code*

```
public class DataBean implements Serializable {
private Date currentTime;

public setDate() {
    currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
 }

public Date getCurrentTime() {
    return currentTime;
 }
}
```

put Object of DataBean in to Bundle:

```
class FirstClass{
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//Your code...

//When you want to start new Activity...
Intent dataIntent =new Intent(FirstClass.this, SecondClass.class);
            Bundle dataBundle=new Bundle();
            DataBean dataObj=new DataBean();
            dataObj.setDate();
            try {
                dataBundle.putByteArray("Obj_byte_array", object2Bytes(dataObj));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            dataIntent.putExtras(dataBundle);

            startActivity(dataIntent);
}
```

Converting objects to byte arrays

```
/**
 * Converting objects to byte arrays
 */
static public byte[] object2Bytes( Object o ) throws IOException {
      ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream( baos );
      oos.writeObject( o );
      return baos.toByteArray();
    }
```

Get Object back from Bundle:

```
class SecondClass{
DataBean dataBean;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//Your code...

//Get Info from Bundle...
    Bundle infoBundle=getIntent().getExtras();
    try {
        dataBean = (DataBean)bytes2Object(infoBundle.getByteArray("Obj_byte_array"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Method to get objects from byte arrays:

```
/**
 * Converting byte arrays to objects
 */
static public Object bytes2Object( byte raw[] )
        throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
      ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream( raw );
      ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream( bais );
      Object o = ois.readObject();
      return o;
    }
```

Hope this will help to other buddies.

Comment: this looks smooth and easy looking at the code. But i feel there is something more on why the SDK doesn't offer something like this to pass objects. Can you tell me something more on this solution?

Comment: No need at all for all that code! Use bundle.putSerializable(objectImplementingSerializable) - this does underneath what your are re-implementing here again...

Answer (score 4):

1.A very direct and easy to use example, make object to be passed implement Serializable.

```
class Object implements Serializable{
    String firstName;
   String lastName;
}
```

2.pass object in bundle

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
Object Object = new Object();
bundle.putSerializable("object", object);
```

3.get passed object from bundle as Serializable then cast to Object.

```
Object object = (Object) getArguments().getSerializable("object");
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question when I was looking for a way to pass a Date object. In my case, as was suggested among the answers, I used Bundle.putSerializable() but that wouldn't work for a complex thing as the described DataManager in the original post.

My suggestion that will give a very similar result to putting said DataManager in the Application or make it a Singleton is to use Dependency Injection and bind the DataManager to a Singleton scope and inject the DataManager wherever it is needed. Not only do you get the benefit of increased testability but you'll also get cleaner code without all of the boiler plate "passing dependencies around between classes and activities" code. [(Robo)Guice](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice) is very easy to work with and the new [Dagger](https://github.com/square/dagger) framework looks promising as well.

Comment: Well, with something like a Date, you could just pass the long value. But, the rest sounds good. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very belated answer to my own question, but it keep getting attention, so I feel I must address it. Most of these answers are correct and handle the job perfectly. However, it depends on the needs of the application. This answer will be used to describe two solutions to this problem.

## Application

The first is the [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html), as it has been the most spoken about answer here. The application is a good object to place entities that need a reference to a Context. A `ServerSocket` undoubtedly would need a context (for file I/o or simple `ListAdapter` updates). I, personally, prefer this route. I like application's, they are useful for context retrieving (because they can be made static and not likely cause a memory leak) and have a simple lifecycle.

## Service

The [Service`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) is second. A `Service`is actually the better choice for my problem becuase that is what services are designed to do:

```
A Service is an application component that can perform long-running operations in
the background and does not provide a user interface.
```

Services are neat in that they have a more defined lifecycle that is easier to control. Further, if needed, services can run externally of the application (ie. on boot). This can be necessary for some apps or just a neat feature.

This wasn't a full description of either, but I left links to the docs for those who want to investigate more. Overall the `Service` is the better for the instance I needed - running a ServerSocket to my SPP device.

Answer (score 0):

another simple way to pass object using a bundle:

- in the class object, create a static list or another data structure with a key
- when you create the object, put it in the list/data structure with the key (es. the long timestamp when the object is created)
- create the method static getObject(long key) to get the object from the list
- in the bundle pass the key, so you can get the object later from another point in the code