# Put Object as intent for next activity

Tags: android, object, android-intent, bundle, parcelable

Is it possible to to put an object of type Object into an intent as a Extra? I have a variable of type object and won't know until it is assigned a value as to what the object datatype is. Maybe something to do with serialization or as a bundle i'm not sure? And then in the next activity how do I then get this value in order to store it in an `ArrayList<Object>` ?

Comment: [This stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249897/how-to-send-objects-through-bundle/13819217#13819217) will help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`Bundle`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) by way of `Intent#putExtra` does not have any function to add an `Object`. You can only pass in a [`Parcelable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) or a [`Serializable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html) object. Any object you want to pass via an `Intent` must implement one of those interfaces. It's recommended to implement `Parcelable` there is a brief guide here: [Pass by value Parameters using Parcelables](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html).

Also this question has more helpful answers: [How to send an object from one Android Activity to another using Intents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-with-intent-putextra)

Comment: How can this method work for an object of type I don't know at the time of parceling?

Comment: This could be expanded a bit I feel. Technically as long as the Object is parcelable or serializable then you can call the toArray function of the List and send it that way.