# Passing a Java object using sharedpreferences in Android

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Can I use Android's sharedpreferences to pass a Java object between different activities?

Comment: Not unless you marshall it, look up Parcleable.

Comment: No.  There is no work around.  You can't pass a pointer.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: In my first activity, an object is created. Then I have several next activities. Each uses only a few attributes of that object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Bundles" are probably the best way to go:

- http://bimbim.in/post/2010/09/27/Android-Passing-object-from-one-activity-to-another.aspx

> Intent and Bundle are two classes to transfer object's from one
>   activity to another activity. You can create bundle object and put
>   them into intent

If you want to pass an "object" in your Bundle, then the object must implement "Parcelable":

- [How to send objects through bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249897/how-to-send-objects-through-bundle)
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

Yet another alternative is to use global state:

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Answer (score 0):

No. For that purpose I suggest creating an implementation of the Application class as a singleton and keeping a reference to your object there.

Edit after reading comments:
Keep in mind though that a singleton has many drawbacks and should be used only if the other solutions are insufficient.

Comment: this still probably indicates a borked part of your design.

Comment: @Kristopher Micinski : How do you mean? Is your objection with implementing the applications class or the Singleton pattern?

Comment: My objection is that too many people want to keep a singleton when they really don't need it.  My objection isn't to your comment.  If you think through it and rationalize it then it's an ok solution.  But there's a very hasty idea that you can just use a "global variable" to hack your design, when in reality you should be able to compartmentalize this better within the pieces of your app.

Comment: I see what you mean. I'm working on and Android application right now and this ended up being the most efficient solution I think. After rereading the question I see now how a singleton might be overkill. I'll add a comment to my answer. Thanks for the input!

Comment: I see how that would be a bad design. Thanks anyway.