# Android: How to send an objects with member objects through bundle?

Tags: android, bundle

I have found a few simple examples of how to do this with an object that contains primitive types. I am working with a class that contains an array of objects as one of its members and several enumeration member variables. How would I store each object? I assume I would have to make both implement Parcelable. Are there any examples out there or others who have dealt with this problem?

[How to send objects through bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249897/how-to-send-objects-through-bundle)

Answer (score 1):

i hope  JSONObject will help you in this . you can put other object in  to one json object by using put method ... and you can send that object by writing it in to any .txt or .json file 
and you can just parse that file and get all those object that you have write in to file

Comment: Why would you use json to serialise the data ? simply using Parcelable is sufficient

Comment: i dont have much idea about Parcelable but as question asked he wants to store each object thats why i suggested jsonobject where as he can store all member object in to one object and just write that object to file and use when ever he wants

Comment: Well his question is probably not well written but his title says he wants to send it via a Bundle. Of course JSON would work but it's not the Android way.

Comment: I already posted something but I guess it wasn't enough so I post a small easy sample too

Answer (score 1):

The [Parcel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html)  interface gives you different possibilities for your array of objects

```
writeParcelableArray(T[] value, int parcelableFlags)
writeStringArray(String[] val)
writeStringList(List<String> val)

readParcelableArray(ClassLoader loader)
readStringList(List<String> list)
readStringArray(String[] val)
```

And for the Enum's you can either save the name and recreate it later using

```
readString()
writeString(String val)
```

Or getting the enum value and using

```
readInt()
writeInt(Int val)
```

Small code sample

```
public class Tag implements Parcelable {

private long id;
private String title;

// ... getter & setters & constructor ...

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
    out.writeLong(id);
    out.writeString(title);
}

public static final transient Parcelable.Creator<Tag> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Tag>() {
    public Tag createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Tag(in);
    }

    public Tag[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Tag[size];
    }
};

protected Tag(Parcel in) {
    readFromParcel(in);
}

protected final void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
    id = in.readLong();
    title = in.readString();
}
}
```