# Android - Saving Grid Layout contents when orientation changes

Tags: android, layout, imageview, grid, orientation

I have a grid layout which is populated with image views. This is a pairs game where the user has to click on images and find a pair. The game itself is fully working but I have one problem which I cannot get around.

When I change orientation I loose the grid. I need some way of saving the grid contents and state so it can display again when orientation changes.

Thankyou

Comment: Hi. Can you provide some code ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the Activity Lifecycle on the official docs https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#asem

Here you can check that when the app changes the orientation, the method called is `onDestroy()` so you have to override the methods `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` to save and instance of the activity and get it in the `onCreate()` function when it's called.

Comment: Thankyou for your quick response. What would I need to put in these methods in order to save the contents of my grid.

Comment: If you have an array with objects to populate the grid, you can save this objects as string values using Gson http://stackoverflow.com/a/14645982/4229896 and save an ArrayList in the bundle and then use . putStringArrayList() to save the data